# Allow my IP only

Tags: connection

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I have a dev test server at home, and we are working on it with a friend.

We use SSH, FTP, and also some port for mail, web, ect...

I want to allow only our ip from where we are working on this server :

- Local network
- IP from my office
- IP from my friend
- IP from my friend office 
  (We work on the server from office for test too)

I've check the logs and I see a lot of try, some people try to login as root, this is why I want to allow only my friend and I to login. But as it's a Web server, we must keep Web and Mail ports open for incoming.

Not sure if I explain fine. How I can do that ? I already try iptable with no luck, still a lot of incoming connection and attempt to login as root.

Can you please let me know how I can proceed easy ?

Thanks and best regards,
GP

Comment: can you post the output of `sudo iptables -L` (it will list all of your current `iptables` rules)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  58.218.198.145       anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination As you can see I already try to block an IP... Because I see more than 65000 try to connect as root.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario you need setup `iptables` rules for this . Also you can user `firewalld` which is rich command for managing firewall in Linux . I'll explain `iptables` here .

Iptables is for ipv4/ipv6 packet filtering for Linux kernel . In *iptables* there are three default tables which each of them contain three default chains :

1. Input
2. Output
3. Forward

Iptables command is following with different options . For your scenario as an example you need to write following commands :

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

These commands only accept ssh connection from port 22 from IP x.x.x.x and every incoming packets will be drop . You can do it for any IP and any Ports you want to server answer . For incoming packets that you don't know  which states are use **RELATED** and **INVALID** in `--state` .

You should notice that `iptables` is sequential rule order . As an example if you block every thing then accept some then you wouldn't get any result because when incoming packet match any rule other rules wouldn't be considered .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the IP from my local computer + from my office for the moment. Now I see that the hackers connection attemps states are in SYN_SENT so it works ! Now if I want to add more IP to allow for SSH, can I do again iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT ? Even if i already set iptables -A INPUT -j DROP ?

Comment: Your welcome . So delete the last line which should your *DROP* action . You can find line number with `iptables -L --line-numbers` then delete with `iptables -D line-number` . After that add other IPs you want to add with `-A` option . Whenever you entered all rules then add `DROP` action .